# How can I show tax per line item at checkout?

Tags: 8, commerce

In D7, there was a module named '[Commerce price by components](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_price_components)' which allowed us to display a price inclusive or exclusive of tax.
I would like to show a detailed tax breakdown at checkout as most of my store's products are tax exempt, but some are not.

Is it possible in D8 to show the a price inclusive and exclusive of tax as two columns in the checkout summary / review table? Or is it possible to show only the tax that is being added?

Comment: Go to URL of `/admin/commerce/config/stores` and edit your store. Checkmark *Display taxes of this type inclusive in product prices.* and save settings.

Comment: This is definitely not the answer!
I'm asking about displaying _only_ the tax component of a price; in this case, in a column in the order summary.